# Как проводить тест кода на пайтон?

Tags: python, отладка

1. Как проводить тесты на валидацию кода на пайтон без IDE и без кучи
   print'ов?
2. Как узнать время выполнения работы программы?
3. Как тестировать код, не засоряя output при этом типом той или иной переменной, длиной списка, не делая кучу if-else блоков, как код ниже?

   ```
   if a + b > z:
       print(a + b)
   else:
       print('Wrong input')
   ```

Comment: Так тестировать код или тестировать пользовательский ввод? В вопросе одно, а в примере кода вижу другое

Comment: речь идет о unit тестах? о профилировании? или о чем-то другом?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman ну тут и о профилировании, и о unit-тестах речь

Comment: лучше разделите этот вопрос на несколько - сейчас он слишком общий и не понятный

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проверять код на валидность можно без print'ов и без IDE'шных инструментов отладки.

Для этого существуют **модуль time** и отладочная функция **assert**. Остановимся на них поподробней.

## Модуль time

Модуль time очень обширен, но подробно рассматривать его для наших целей я не вижу смысла, ибо полагаю, что нам интересно только узнать время выполнения программы в секундах.
Чтобы узнать это, достаточно импортировать модуль и запомнить время старта программы с помощью функции time.time()

```
import time

t = time.time() # запоминаем время на момент начала работы программы
print(t)
```

Теперь переменная t хранит в себе время в секундах с начала нашей эры от момента начала программы.

Чтобы узнать как долго происходило выполнение программы нам нужно вновь обратиться к time.time() и вычесть из этого значения наше значение t:

```
import time

t = time.time() # запоминаем время на момент начала работы программы
# блоки кода
print('Время выполнения', time.time() - t, 'cек')
```

Но не забывайте, что конфигурация влияет на время выполнения, поэтому одно значение у вас может отличаться от значения на другой машине. Чтобы снизить разницу я рекомендую пройти курсы по алгоритам.

## Assert

Assert это такая отладочная штука, которая проверяет условие на истинность, и если условие истинно, то код работает дальше, а если **ложно**, то assert **возбуждает исключение** типа **AssertionError**.

Как с этим работать? Очень просто. Нужно предположить как будет вести себя код, какими будут значения в той или иной строке и для проверки выставить assert с условиями на истинность этих предположений.

Например, давайте сделаем список из int значений, элементы которого будут нацело делиться на 2:

```
lst = [int(x) for x in range(0, 101, 2)]
```

Мы хотим вывести наши значения и предполагаем, что они:

1. нацело делятся на 2
2. имеют тип int

Перебираем список и перед тем как вывести значения расставляем наши assert'ы

```
for x in lst:
    assert x % 2 == 0 # проверяем, что число делится без остатка на 2
    assert type(x) == int # что его тип - int
    assert x % 2 == 0 and type(x) == int # можно строить более длинные и сложные конструкции
    # assert x % 2 == 0 and type(x) == float # а это мы уже не пройдём, потому что тип int
    print(x) # наконец выводим значение
```

## Пример со всем сразу

Допустим у нас есть файл с логами перемещения в формате `x y z`. Иными словами, файл с координатами.

Мы импортируем модуль time и random (он нам понадобится) и сохраняем время начала работы программы.

```
import time, random

t = time.time()
```

Создадим файл, который будем читать:

```
# создаём файл
file = open('coordinates.log', 'w')

for x in range(10000):
    x = random.uniform(-100, 100)
    y = random.uniform(-100, 100)
    z = random.uniform(-100, 100)
    file.write(str(x) + ' ' + str(y) + ' ' + str(z) + '\n')

file.close()
```

Затем открываем файл с логами и читаем его:

```
with open('coordinates.log', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip()
        # line = line.split() # разбиение не проводим

        assert len(line) == 3 and type(line) == list # и поэтому тут получаем ошибку
```

Давайте исправим ошибку и добавим split(), а также добавим в код некоторый функционал

```
import time, random

t = time.time()
prev_coor = [0, 0, 0] # переменная, хранящая предыдущие координаты
                      # по моей задумке, изначально это нулевые координаты

# создаём файл
file = open('coordinates.log', 'w')

# будем генерировать случайные float числа от -100 до 100
for x in range(10000):
    x = random.uniform(-100, 100)
    y = random.uniform(-100, 100)
    z = random.uniform(-100, 100)
    file.write(str(x) + ' ' + str(y) + ' ' + str(z) + '\n')

file.close()

# открываем созданный файл и файл для вывода
with open('coordinates.log', 'r') as f, open('coor_difference.txt', 'w') as d:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip()
        line = line.split() # добавляем split() и исправляем нашу ошибку

        assert len(line) == 3 and type(line) == list # и код проходит проверку
                                                     # а если не проходит
                                                     # значит файл с bad data

        try:
            line = [float(x) for x in line] # приводим каждый элемент строки к числу
        except ValueError:
            raise Exception ('Bad data') # не получилось? - райзим Exception Bad data

# по поводу блока try-except хотелось бы сказать, что если бы мы не использовали данный блок,
# а просто делали приведение типа, и данные были бы плохие, то
# исключение было бы возбуждено само собой, но мне хотелось показать, что исключения
# можно не только отлавливать, но также и возбуждать их с помощью raise

        for x in line:
            assert type(x) == float # проверяем, что мы привели каждый элемент к типу float

        # ну и, к примеру выводим разницу между текущими и предыдущими координатами в файл, открытый для вывода
        d.write(str([round(curr - prev, 2) for curr, prev in zip(line, prev_coor)]) + '\n')
        prev_coor = line

# не забываем про то, что нам интересно сколько было затрачено времени
print('Время выполнения', time.time() - t, 'cек')
```

## Более интересный пример:

Например, мы создаём какой-либо функционал в классе. В нашем случае это простейший калькулятор. Как проверить, что функционал реализован верно? Мы запустим определённое количество проверок, в которых будем инициализировать экземпляры класса с определёнными значениями и будем проверять, сходятся ли наши ответы.

В данном случае функционал встроен в пайтон, поэтому правильны ли ответы, мы будем смотреть путём идентичных операций.

```
class Calculator(object):
    def __init__ (self, l, r):
        self.l = l
        self.r = r

    def plus(self):
        return self.l + self.r

    def min(self):
        return self.l - self.r

    def div(self):
        return self.l / self.r

    def mul(self):
        return self.l * self.r

    def get_items(self):
        return (self.l, self.r)


for x in range(100):
    a = random.randint(-100, 100)
    b = random.randint(-100, 100)

    calc = Calculator(a, b)

    assert calc.plus() == a + b # верно ли реализована оперция сложения
    assert calc.min() == a - b # верно ли реализована операция вычитания
    assert calc.div() == a / b # верно ли реализована операция деления
    assert calc.mul() == a * b # верно ли реализована операция умножения

    # также выводим результаты в файл
    c = open('calc_output.txt', 'a') # ключ a открывает файл на дозапись

    c.write(str(calc.get_items()) + ' операция +; результат - ' + str(calc.plus()) + '\n')
    c.write(str(calc.get_items()) + ' операция -; результат - ' + str(calc.min()) + '\n')
    c.write(str(calc.get_items()) + ' операция /; результат - ' + str(calc.div()) + '\n')
    c.write(str(calc.get_items()) + ' операция *; результат - ' + str(calc.mul()) + '\n')

    c.close()
```

Comment: При тестировании лучше не использовать случайные числа, потому что в реальной ситуации какой-то тест может упасть, а может не упасть, нет гарантированной повторяемости результатов. Выход - либо руками проверять в нескольких точках внутри области определения, граничные случаи, и падение за пределами области определения, либо использовать, например, [hypothesis](http://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Вообще, для юнит-тестирования стоит использовать уже существующие фреймворки (тот же unittest, присутствующий в Python "из коробки", либо другой тестовый фреймворк, я пользуюсь py.test).

Comment: @insolor ну, я не тестировщик, как правильно делать тесты меня не учили и я не учился. Единственный косяк, который тут может быть (по этим тестам и этим задачам), как я вижу, заключается в том, что сгенерится ноль, и потом на этот ноль будет происходить попытка деления, что вызовет исключение ZeroDivisonError. А рандомизация, на мой взгляд, как раз для того и используется, чтобы проверить, что код работает верно. А то если вечно тестить на одних входных данных, то не факт, что output будет верным и при других

Comment: Еще раз: рандомизация не даст стабильного результата. Если тест при одних и тех же условиях может упасть, а может не упасть - это плохой тест. Есть отличный доклад от Ned Batchelder (на английском) по поводу тестирования, начиная от ручного тестирования до юниттестов: [Getting Started Testing](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/test0.html) (видео, транскрипт и слайды)

Comment: @insolor окей, гляну, спасибо. Тут тест не упадёт в любом случае, исключая возбуждение исключения, которое я уже описал выше. Ну а по поводу py.test, unittest и doctest... Это инструменты всё же, я же хотел показать базовые вещи тем, кто отлаживает код путём вывода данных в консоль. Я не думаю, что ответ стоит дополнять разбором unittest'а или py.test'а. Мне кажется, это уже отдельный вопрос.

Comment: По поводу ZeroDivisioError, у unittest есть свои assert'ы на любой случай жизни, в том числе проверка на то, что выполнение кода вызывает исключение (если код в данной ситуации должен вызывать исключение). У других тестовых фреймворков тоже есть такие возможности. На самом деле - тестовые фреймворки это не инструмент тестера, это инструмент программиста. Почему не просто ассерты? Например, потому что тестовые фреймворки могут например автоматически показать почему именно зафейлил ассерт (какие данные ожидались, а какие были получены), и это без лишних телодвижений со стороны программиста.

Comment: Под падением теста я имею в виду тот случай, когда тест показывает ошибку там где она действительно есть. Если волей рандома тест может иногда обнаружить существующую ошибку, а иногда нет - какой смысл в этом тесте?

Comment: @insolor по-вашему эти тесты могут упасть?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56877/discussion-between-insolor-and-kit-scribe).